# Which index or query will have best performance?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have table with 600k rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `vector` (
  `word_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `а` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    [........]
  `ю` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `я` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total` int(8) AS (а+б+в+г+д+e+ё+ж+з+и+й+к+л+м+н+о+п+
                     р+с+т+у+ф+х+ц+ч+ш+щ+ъ+ь+ы+э+ю+я) PERSISTENT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `vector`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`word_id`),
  ADD KEY `а` (`а`),
    [....]
  ADD KEY `ш` (`ш`),
  ADD KEY `ы` (`ы`),
  ADD KEY `ь` (`ь`),
  ADD KEY `ъ` (`ъ`),
  ADD KEY `total` (`total`),
  ADD KEY `а_2` 
    (`а`,`б`,`в`,`г`,`д`,`e`,`ж`,`з`,`и`,`й`,`к`,`л`,`м`,`н`,`о`,`п`,
     `р`,`с`,`т`,`у`,`ф`,`х`,`ц`,`ч`,`ш`,`щ`,`ъ`,`ь`,`ы`,`э`,`ю`,`я`);
```

I using query:

```
select sql_no_cache `word_id`
    from `vector` use index(а_2)
    where а<=2
      AND б=0 AND в=0 AND г=0 AND д=0 AND е=0 AND ё=0 AND ж=0 AND з=0
      AND и=0 AND й=0 AND к=0 AND л=0 AND м=0
      AND н<=1
      AND о=0 AND п=0 AND р=0 AND с=0 AND т=0 AND у=0 AND ф=0 AND х=0 AND ц=0
      AND ч=0 AND ш=0 AND щ=0 AND ъ=0 AND ь=0 AND ы=0 AND э=0 AND ю=0 AND я=0
      AND word_id != 804272 limit 500
```

this take about 0.35s when using combined index a_2 - how I can do it faster?

profiling:

```
Sending Data    344.5 ms    99.85%  1   344.5 ms
Preparing   157 µs  0.05%   1   157 µs
Statistics  98 µs   0.03%   1   98 µs
Starting    82 µs   0.02%   1   82 µs
[--CUT--]
```

EXPLAIN of query:

```
id select_type table  type  possible_keys key key_len ref  rows   Extra
1  SIMPLE      vector range а_2           а_2 5       NULL 292073 Using index condition; Using where
```

w/o use index(а_2)

```
1 SIMPLE vector ref PRIMARY,а,б,в,г,д,ё,ж,з,и,й,к,л,м,н,о,п,р,с,т,у,ф,...и 1 const 568037 Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the execution plan from `EXPLAIN`. Also post the `EXPLAIN` from the same query without the `use index(a_2)`.

Comment: added profiling and explain

Comment: Our comments crossed paths. :-) Can you also add the `EXPLAIN` for the same `SELECT` without the `use index(a_2)`? I'm pretty sure that it is the cause of your performance issue. It's usually a much better idea to let the database decide which index it should use rather than forcing it to use a specific one.

Comment: added, but with other indexes it takes 0.5s per query

Answer (score 0):

- 35 indexes is a lot.  And most will never be used.
- `USE INDEX` may help some times, but hurt other times.
- There is no *good* index for the schema and table formulated that way.

If you are looking for words with certain letters, then I have several out-of-the-box ideas.  (Some will help more than others.)

**total**

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE total <= 3
      AND ...
```

might work a lot faster.

**REGEXP**:  If you are using MySQL 8.0 (which has an improved `REGEXP`) or MariaDB, then

```
... AND word REGEXP '^[ан]*$' ...
```

*may* lead to another approach.

**bits**: I'm also ponding a 32-bit `INT UNSIGNED` that indicates which characters have non-zero counts.

**Sorting**: And another thought is to have another column with the "sorted" letters sorted.  Then it is an instant test to say

```
WHERE sorted_word IN  ('', 'а', 'аа', 'ан', 'аан', 'н')
```

**Sorting and REGEXP**: (not as fast, but simpler):

```
WHERE sorted_word REGEXP '^а{0,2}н{0,1}$'
```

Some would necessitate having the `word` in the same table and indexed.

However, I am assuming you are looking for short words containing only `а` and `н`?  If that is not what you are looking for, then please elaborate; there may be some other out-of-the-box idea that will help.

Comment: short word just from example - it can be much more letters 10-20

Comment: Regexp will not fullscan??

Comment: @rst630 - `REGEXP` will do a full scan.  So that solution is not viable.

Comment: @rst630 - 10-20 letters.  Then elaborate on why your example had "<=2".  Is it some set of words?  Or not really "words" but some kind of "code"?

Comment: 2 is how sum of letters in searching word

Answer (score 0):

ё is not covered by you index `а_2` (i assume you want to index all columns used in the where clause). Fix and try again to see if speed has increased.

on a second note: The order of the indexed columns is important. Putting columns with high cardinality at the beginning of the index will increase speed but makes the index only usable for certain selects.

Comment: ё is't in index because 32 limit for combined index, and I exclude ё as not often used char